# How do you make a detail view draw from a property list?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have created a property list that has a path of logic like this:

```
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Construction</string>
        <key>Children</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Advisory Services</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Disputes Services</string>
                <key>Details</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Title</key>
                    <string>Disputes Services</string>
                    <key>Associated Image</key>
                    <string>Construction_iPhone.png</string>
                    <key>Industry Info</key>
                    <string>Planning and executing a construction project is a complex process that can be thrown off course by a variety of factors.  Many root causes of delivery overrun are seeded during project development and procurement. Through our extensive construction dispute experience, we have discerned patterns of cost and schedule overruns and project failures that repeat themselves among projects. We leverage this insight to help owners, contractors, providers of capital and counsel identify and proactively manage potential problems throughout the lifecycle of large construction projects.   We also help to manage the risks associated with any claims arising in those projects, particularly those in the infrastructure, healthcare and energy industries.</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
```

I have created a drill-down application that essentially brings you down to the list of strings. I want to set up my detail view controller now, so I have created a few variables to get me started.

```
//DetailViewController.h

IBOutlet NSString *title;
IBOutlet UIImage *associatedImage;
IBOutlet NSString *IndustryInfo;
```

I dragged an image and two boxes of text into interface builder. Linked 'em accordingly. It is just an image at the top of the page and then two boxes of text, nothing too complex.

Obviously, I would like to set it up so it just uses the property list to get this information. Problem is that I'm new to iOS development. How would I set up a method using objectForKey in my implementation to parse out the information that I want and display it on the screen? Also, how would I set up the UIImage considering the fact that I set it up as a string in my .plist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the plist file with [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:...]` or `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:...]` depending on your plist. I'm not sure how you have the image set up, but you could load it with `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` or `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:...]`.